# 2 Number float array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I was doing some training course, and this question still has my attention.

*Question:*

**Declare an array of type float named math_constants. 
The array should be big enough to hold 2 numbers.**

Why is

```
float math_constants[2];
```

Correct?

And why is

```
float math_constants[1];
```

Wrong?

It might be a newbie mistake, but its confusing me.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is correct?

Comment: Because an array starts counting at 0

Comment: @Tareffic Your question is not specific to iOS, that's why the tag has been removed.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe i added it, because i was following an iOS course

Comment: Now the misunderstanding is clear. The integer in brackets is the size (i.e. the number of elements) of that array, not its upper limit of indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number within square brackets is the size of the array, i.e., the number of elements in the array. This is different from the fact that indexing of the elements starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

c syntax for array

arrayType array_name[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]

in the case of your example math_constants[1] can hold 1 value, namely when you try to access math_constants[0]

similarly , math_constants[2] can hold 2 value,  math_constants[0] and math_constants[1]

Comment: Your syntax example is confusing. You probably wanted to explain how to **define** an array but you omitted the type.

Comment: I forgot to include that.